# What is the default behavior of %install?

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild

I am attempting to build an RPM using the `-bb` flag (%prep %build %install %check package). This is the output of the %install step:

```
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.2kgeNY
+ umask 022
+ cd /<redacted>/BUILD
+ '[' /<redacted>/BUILDROOT/<redacted>.i386 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /<redacted>/BUILDROOT/<redacted>.i386
++ dirname /<redacted>/BUILDROOT/<redacted>.i386
+ mkdir -p /<redacted>/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /<redacted>/BUILDROOT/<redacted>.i386
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile /usr/bin/python 1
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
```

Here are the contents of that tmp file:

```
  RPM_SOURCE_DIR="/<redacted>/SOURCES"
  RPM_BUILD_DIR="/<redacted>/BUILD"
  RPM_OPT_FLAGS="-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m32 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -mfpmath=sse -fasynchronous-unwind-tables"
  RPM_LD_FLAGS="-Wl,-z,relro "
  RPM_ARCH="i386"
  RPM_OS="linux"
  export RPM_SOURCE_DIR RPM_BUILD_DIR RPM_OPT_FLAGS RPM_LD_FLAGS RPM_ARCH RPM_OS
  RPM_DOC_DIR="/usr/share/doc"
  export RPM_DOC_DIR
  RPM_PACKAGE_NAME="<redacted>"
  RPM_PACKAGE_VERSION="<redacted>"
  RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE="<redacted>"
  export RPM_PACKAGE_NAME RPM_PACKAGE_VERSION RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE
  LANG=C
  export LANG
  unset CDPATH DISPLAY ||:
  RPM_BUILD_ROOT="/<redacted>/BUILDROOT/<redacted>.i386"
  export RPM_BUILD_ROOT

  PKG_CONFIG_PATH="%{_PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig"
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  set -x
  umask 022
  cd "/<redacted>/BUILD"
    [ "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT" != "/" ] && rm -rf "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}"
    mkdir -p `dirname "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"`
    mkdir "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"




    /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot

    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress

    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump

    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
    /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile /usr/bin/python 1
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
```

I have not overwritten the %install behavior in my spec file. My spec file looks like this:

```
<stuff>
%prep
%build
%install
%files
<more stuff>
```

Is the default %install behavior defined in the `rpm-builder` documentation anywhere? How do I know what it's going to execute?

Comment: Can you still access `/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.2kgeNY` after `rpmbuild` completes? That will list everything run by `%install`.

Comment: no, it seems to be getting deleted.

Comment: The [docs](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html) and the Fedora [wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#.25install_section) don't give much away.

Comment: I added the contents of that file to my question.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you removed parts of the paths - it's unlikely it could reveal much about your system.

Comment: they contained product names and versions.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

The `%install` phase in an RPM spec file is supposed to create a filesystem hierarchy that is unpacked into a system when you install the resulting rpm. This whole hierarchy is to be created in the `%{buildroot}` (AKA `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`) directory by the commands found in the `%install` section. Its contents is inserted verbatim (upon RPM macro expansions) into a script that is interpreted by shell - that is the line:

```
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.2kgeNY
```

Now if you leave the %install phase empty, the contents of the script is not - because it initialises various things that a packager will very likely want to use during the installation (`$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` is one of the important ones).

What exactly the initialisation does is distribution dependent - check the contents of the rpm package (`rpm -ql rpm`), files like `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` (might be in somewhere else on your system) are good candidates to contain (RPM) macros that are expanded around what you put in the `%install` phase of your the spec file.

That said, most often (especially with software that uses autotools) the main part of the `%install` phase should be

```
make install DESTDIR=%{buildroot}
```

The `%make_install` macro should do exactly that. Some distributions also have a similar RPM macro "shortcut" like e.g. [`%makeinstall` in openSUSE](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/Base:System/rpm/rpm-suse_macros), which may offer some additional features over the generic upstream one.

Comment: I tried writing my own `%install` code in my spec file, but it is executing it is still executing its own code right before mine.

Comment: And it always will - re-read the answer please.

Comment: ah, I misread your answer, I thought it was initializing iff I "leave the %install phase empty"

Comment: basically my problem is that the %install is doing an rm -rf of my BUILDROOT directory but later steps depend on having some of those files there.

Comment: Yes, it removes `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` and than it re-creates it - that is to ensure the tree contained therein is not going to be tainted - it's far from being secure (racy) so it won't prevent malicious activities, but it's enough to make sure something doesn't go wrong accidentally. The `%install` phase should be contained in the place where you have four empty lines in the script (I suppose you have these in the `%install` section). What follows are various checks and so on (debug symbols stripping, for example).

Comment: thanks, the file I was looking for was `/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/macros`. I had to comment out a line in that file to get what I wanted.